# Live Stream h.264 video to client webpage using Gstreamer and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gstreamer, live-streaming

I want to leverage the following example to accept more than one camera and stream in to a client web page.

https://delog.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/stream-live-webm-video-to-browser-using-node-js-and-gstreamer/

For reference here is my gstreamer command:

gst-launch-1.0 -ve \
videotestsrc is-live=true  ! video/x-raw,width=640,width=480,framerate=10/1 ! timeoverlay ! queue ! videoconvert ! vaapih264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! matroskamux streamable=true ! queue leaky=2 ! tcpserversink port=9001 host=127.0.0.1 recover-policy=keyframe sync-method=latest-keyframe \
videotestsrc is-live=true  ! video/x-raw,width=640,width=480,framerate=10/1 ! timeoverlay ! queue ! videoconvert ! vaapih264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! matroskamux streamable=true ! queue leaky=2 ! tcpserversink port=9002 host=127.0.0.1 recover-policy=keyframe sync-method=latest-keyframe \

Two cameras streaming to ports 9001 and 9002.

The majority of the work happens app.get() function.  How can I modify this to handle more than one socket.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var http = require('http')
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var date = new Date();

  res.writeHead(200, {
      'Date': date.toUTCString(),
      'Connection': 'close',
      'Cache-Control': 'private',
      'Content-Type': 'video/webm',
      //'Content-Type': video/x-matroska,
      'Server': 'CustomStreamer/0.0.1',
  });

  var net = require('net');
  var socket = net.connect(9001, function () {
      socket.on('close', function (had_error) {
          res.end();
      });
      socket.on('data', function (data) {
          res.write(data);
      });   

  });
  socket.on('error', function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
});

console.log("Server listening on port.... 8001");
httpServer.listen(8001);
```

thanks!

Update: Created another socket and  I was able to grab data from two different sockets.  There is probably a more clever way to do this, but for now I repeat the socket code, name them socket1 and socket2, and using print statements I feel reasonable confident I"m grabbing data from the two cameras.  Now I need to link the video to my .html file.

```
var socket1 = net.connect(9001, function () {
      socket1.on('close', function (had_error) {
          res.end();
      });
      socket1.on('data', function (data) {
          res.write(data);
      });   

  });
var socket2 = net.connect(9001, function () {
      socket2.on('close', function (had_error) {
          res.end();
      });
      socket2.on('data', function (data) {
          res.write(data);
      });   

  });

  socket1.on('error', function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
  socket2.on('error', function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
```